# React-router-dom Link change the URL but it doesn't render the component in Rect JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using React js components and want to render something by access some URL
so problem is when i click on the Link it change the URL but does not render the component, I have to refresh the page so that it render (as i said URL changes)
I am access URL `http://localhost/3000/product/32423432wew23` the URL change to this and refresh the page it render the product of this id, BUT BY REFRESHING THE PAGE.

App.js

```
import "./App.css";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from './store';
import MainRoute from "./Route/MainRoute";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"
function App() {
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainRoute/>   
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MainRoute.js

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import  { Alert }  from "../Components/Alert";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route,Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
// import HomePage from "../Components/Pages/HomePage";
import Login from '../Components/Login/Login';
import SignUp1 from '../Components/Signup/SignUp1';
import ForgotPassword1 from "../Components/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword1";
// import Profile from "../Components/Pages/Profile";
import { AddPost } from "../Components/AddPost/AddPost";
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar/Navbar";
// import {DetailProduct} from "../Components/Pages/DetailProduct";
import Footer from "../Components/Footer/Footer";
import Banner from "../Components/Banner/Banner";
import { Products } from "../Components/Products/Products";
import { EditProfile } from "../Components/EditProfile/EditProfile";
import { DetailProductPage } from "../Components/DetailProductPage/DetailProductPage";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {getProducts} from "../Actions/products"
import { UploadProduct } from "../Components/UploadProduct/UploadProduct";
import MyPosts from "../Components/MyPosts/MyPosts";

const MainRoute = () => {

  const [alert, setalert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setalert({
      msg: message,
      type: type,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      setalert(null);
    }, 1500);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Navbar showAlert={showAlert} />
        <Switch>
          <Router  exact path="/" component={() => <Redirect to="/products" />}>
          </Router>
          <Router  exact path="/products">
            <Banner/>
            <Products/>   
          </Router>
          <Route exact path="/login">
            <Login showAlert={showAlert} />
          </Route>
          <Route  exact path="/signup">
            <SignUp1 showAlert={showAlert} />
          </Route>
          <Route  exact path="/forgotPassword">
            <ForgotPassword1 showAlert={showAlert}/>
          </Route>
          <Route  exact path="/viewProfile/:id">
            <EditProfile/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/product/upload">
            <UploadProduct/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/product/:id">
            <DetailProductPage/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/mypost/:id">
            <MyPosts/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );
};

export default MainRoute;
```

This Line is in the product. js well it's a material ui card where a action is add (view) when clicking on it detailProduct page should have to be rendered but it doesn't.

product.js

```
import {Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Link to={`/product/${product._id}`} style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
          <Button size="small">View</Button>
          </Link>
```

DetailProductPage.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const DetailProductPage = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{marginTop: "70px"}}>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

(Rendering Hello for testing)

If anyone know what's the problem please let me know
TIA

Comment: Where is this `Link` located? Is it a child of `Router`? Also what page are you coming *from*?

Comment: Using Link like this not a child of Router
```
<CardActions style={{ marginLeft: "220px" }}>
          <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`} style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
          <Button size="small">View</Button>
          </Link>
          
        </CardActions>
```


i am at http://localhost/3000 and products renders there when i click on specific product then http://localhost/3000/product/:id should have to render

Comment: That could be your issue then. `Link` doesn't just change the URL, it informs `react-router` that it needs to re-render and set new context values. `Router` is what initializes that context, so if the `Link` is not within that context, it cannot inform `react-router` of changes.

Comment: Please can you tell what changes i have to made? for working?

Comment: You mean to say i have to wrap Link in Router? if  yes then i do that nothing happened.

Comment: What Brian is saying, and what I suspect, is that you are likely rendering more than one router. The links and routes each use the routing context of the closest `Router` above them in the ReactTree. The routers don't "talk" to each other though, they simply provide a routing context to the tree below them. If the links are in one router and the routes in the other, then they don't work together to react to the URL being updated.

Comment: Can you tell me please what I have to do now? I am confused!!

Comment: Ensure you've only one `Router` wrapping your app. You can also provide us more complete code so we can see everything from the root router all the way to where you are rendering `Route` and `Link` components. Where is the Product.js being rendered with the links? What is the `Navbar` rendering? etc...

Comment: There are many files in the project can you share your github name so that i share it with you so you can see?

Comment: And also there is only one `Router` in my app

Comment: Is your github repo public? If so can you share a link to it?

Comment: My repo is not public :|

Comment: I see, then the best thing to do is to distill your project down to a minimal reproducible code example for here and if we can resolve it hopefully you can take the knowledge gained back to your private code and apply it.

Comment: I update my code here now you can see if there is any problem??? i am still facing the same issue not rendered the detailProductPage

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this might be the reason, but if you are using react 18 with react-router-dom-V5, it will not work in react.strictMode, you will have to remove the   <React.StrictMode>  tag from your index.js or update to V6 of react-router-dom

Comment: nice catch, most examples are over react-route-dom@5, result natural try that version generating this issue.